# Hide Firefox (~114+) title bar in Kubuntu (23.04)

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, 23.04

In Kubuntu 23.04 the option to hide the titlebar is missing:

[image]

This happens with version 114.02, be it local ("portable"), snap, or  mozilla-team PPA version. The same with beta and nightly (115, 116).

In a "portable" non-snap ESR version (102.12.0esr) the setting is present but it does nothing anymore, although it worked until some time ago.

[image]

The older solution of using `true` for `about:config` - `browser.tabs.drawInTitlebar` option doesn't work either.

Is this related to some update in Plasma integration packages for gtk apps or what?

---

As said in a comment, and as confirmed by me too, on a separate machine that runs Kubuntu 22.04 the problem is absent with latest 114 as well as with latest nightly 116. This looks independent of the  Firefox version.

Comment: Can you try the Firefox PPA https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/124466

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi - You mean you use that and don't have the issue? I will test the PPA although I'm using now a local/portable 114 with the same problem. But I will test the nightlies too and report back.

Comment: I am using Firefox 114.0.2 from the PPA in Kubuntu 22.04, and cannot reproduce this issue

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi - I have the same problem in the PPA stable version as well as in the local/portable nightly. I may be that you don't have the problem because you haven't got the update for some Plasma-gtk compatibility package I have in 23.04. - That update seems to be the cause of other UI problems I face since recently, namely small fonts that don't scale with the rest of the UI.

Comment: Same problem after FF updated to 114. Using PPA on Lubuntu.

Comment: @slacle - And can you remove the titlebar?

Comment: @cipricus - No, that's the problem I have, that I can't remove the title bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this won't be fixed or as a workaround:

- add a window rule to hide the Firefox title bar:

[image]

- install addons that provide the window buttons: [maximize](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/movable-window-maximize-button/) (links to the other two at that page)

(There are other addons for buttons, but the above give me the best KDE integration.)

I think this new configuration looks and acts even better than the old one!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat workaround/hack is to right click on the title bar and select Un/Decorate. This will remove the title bar, but it will also remove the minimize, maximize, and close buttons along with it.

Comment: If you can remove the titlebar, then you cam add buttons with addons (as in my answer) and get the exact look we had with the old FF setting, and in fact a better look imo.